# Is 12V in car same as in computer power supply?

Tags: power-supply

I have bought a car camera with LCD monitor, exactly this one http://www.dx.com/p/5-0-lcd-car-rear-view-stand-security-monitor-camera-w-5-ir-led-kit-480-x-272-pixels-153662

It is powered by 12V.

Can I try it out at home by connecting it to my PC power supply? There is 12V available in the molex connector.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can get 12 V from your PC power supply. But you must know how to start it outside of the PC (the `PS_ON` pin).

Also, most PC PSUs need a load on the +5V voltage to fully start up.

However if you use the PSU while in the PC box, there's no need for load and `PS_ON`, just be sure to do the wiring with all the devices powered off, to avoid ESD.

For your camera, you need the black wire (GND) and the yellow one (+12V).

Answer (score 2):

You can bring out an HDD plug and tap into the 12V on the side of your PC. The two centre pins are ground.

Since it is made for a car, the unit must be designed for abnormal automotive range 11 to 15 V , normally 12.5 to 14.2, so 12 V +/-5% on your PC is ideal.

Comment: I'd like to mark also your answer, but it's possible to mark only one answer. Thanks! Usefull information.